# Generating push certificate ios php

Tags: php, ios, certificate

I am trying to make a push certificate for using with my app. In development part.

I have the code for push notification in server already done but it has a part in which it says:

```
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'iOS_pushCertificate\ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
```

I need to create thatn ck.pem and also the passphrase. I don't know where do I have to set the passphrase or how to create the certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/) has a great tutorial in [his page](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/) explaining exactly that.

Comment: Thanks man. I already created the files and passphrase. The problem now is that push notifications are not reaching my phone. Iphone is registered, push is ok but they not reach... I will check that now.